# Read message from exchange with Rabbit Template

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I'm using `rabbitTemplate` in this way:

```xml
<bean id="rabbitConnFactory" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>localhost</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Spring AMQP Template -->
<bean id="rabbitTemplate" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="rabbitConnFactory" />
</bean>

<!-- Spring AMQP Admin -->
<bean id="rabbitAdmin" class="org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin">
    <constructor-arg ref="rabbitConnFactory" />
</bean>
```

send to exchange:

```
rabbitTemplate.setExchange(exchange);
rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(message);
```

read from exchange:

```
rabbitTemplate.setExchange(exchange);
rabbitTemplate.setQueue(exchange);                //?
Object msg = rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert();
return msg;
```

(I need to set the exchange runtime, because I got it from the database)

but `msg` is always `null`.

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/core/RabbitTemplate.html#receiveAndConvert%28java.lang.String%29) receiveAndConvert method can return `null` if there is nothing in queue.